# how to read a POST request content with python

Tags: python, post, web-scraping, python-requests

Hi  when im trying to send a POST request i got 200 status code and i can read page.text but when i have trouble with finding element by xpath
sorry for bad english

```py
import requests
from lxml import html
cookies = {
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.2008948104.1563397982',
    'kfacommnet': 'f5e38c05-1e26-42ce-8794-afbded5e6ee1',
    'kfasession': '1rgbtjwd4dhjkbi3lyrwyzhk',
    'cookie_matching': 'true',
    'pushNotification-shownCount-2195': '15',
    'pushNotification-notWantPopUp-2195': 'true',
    'tlc': 'true',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.109054603.1563596637',
}

headers = {
    'Origin': 'http://www.kanoon.ir',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,fa-IR;q=0.8,fa;q=0.7,fr-CH;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.4',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Referer': 'http://www.kanoon.ir/Public/SuperiorsRankBased?type=3',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

data = '{"dept":"1","sahmieh":"2","rank":"345","reshte":null,"year":"97","univercity":null,"type":"3"}'
response = requests.post('http://www.kanoon.ir/Public/SuperiorsRankBasedShowSuperiors', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data, verify=False)
page=response.text
tree = html.fromstring(page)
img = tree.xpath('//*[@id="header_area"]/div[1]/a/img')
print(img)
```

Comment: What's the Error you are getting? Is the element found? Are you sure this is the correct XPATH for the element you are looking for?

Comment: Can you please create an example that concentrates on the problem and contains sample input and output data?

Comment: i've got nothing im sure XPATH is correct i copied that from chrome

Comment: display `response.text` to see HTML and check (on your eyes) if this element exists in HTML. Or maybe you see warning or error message  in HTML.

Comment: I tried code and there is no even `tree.xpath('//img')`. Maybe you have to  `get()` page to get new cookies. Or maybe you have to login to this page before you can post data.

Comment: i found this element in response.text

Answer (score 1):

After `page=response.text` add a print statement like this `print(page)` and check the output of the print statement and correct your xpath by looking at the output. Because the current xpath that you have specified is not there.

Comment: `response.text` should be fine considering that they are creating the `tree` using `html.fromstring()`.

Comment: `response.content` returns `bytes` objects, while `response.text` returns `str` objects.

Comment: Does the POST request return something???  You should check the status first ```response.status_code```